# What are some best practices for deploying multiple microservices at the same time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, microservices, continuous-deployment

I have been struggling with the best way to deploy multiple microservices at the same time if there is a change that affects more than one service.

While I'd be interested in any general approaches, let me provide a specific example I'm running into.

Our company uses AWS and Elastic Beanstalk to deploy microservice containers for a web site that are relatively decoupled. Right now our web application consists of:

- A SPA written in Angular, deployed and hosted in an S3 bucket (Call
  it SPA)
- A webapi service, written in .NET Core, dockerized, and deployed to
  an elastic beanstalk application (Call it WebAPI)
- An integration service, written in Node.JS, dockerized, and deployed
  to an elastic beanstalk application (Call it IntService)

The SPA and WebAPI talk via a REST API

The WebAPI and IntService are loosely coupled and talk to each other through an AWS SQS Queue.

If we have a change to any one of these services, our deploy process is fairly straightforward. For example, if we have a change to the WebAPI, we spin up a new elastic beanstalk application environment, deploy there, then swap the URLs (so basic blue-green deployment).

However, I'm struggling with the right approach if there is a change that affects multiple services. For example, say there is a feature that requires changes to both WebAPI and IntService. Since each of these live in their own repo, they each have their own CI and CD pipelines independent of each other.

If just one service is deployed, the whole app might break. How do people handle this type of deploy? Do you clone both the WebAPI and IntService environments, deploy both of them, then swap both URLs, just making sure you do it at about the same time to minimize the window of time where only one service is active?

Alternatively, we were looking at using an API gateway. But would that mean every time we wanted to deploy we'd create a new API gateway stage? If we do that, is the blue-green deployment 'swap' actually happening in the API Gateway?

Sorry if this is confusing, but I'm just trying to wrap my head around what I have to imagine is a fairly common problem with microservices.

Comment: are you using ubuntu for your server at S3 bucket?

Comment: No - just using the 'static website hosting' feature of s3 buckets

Answer (score 6):

This is what I refer to as changing a wheel while the car is moving.

The whole point of micro services is to make them decoupled so you can release any given part on its own.

You therefore have to make incremental changes that are backwards compatible with each other.

This is similar to how you change your database. Say you want to remove a Boolean column and replace it with en enum. You do this not by changing the database and all the code at once, as that will have not only the deployment issue but also, what if something goes wrong and you have to roll back? Instead, you are better off first adding the new column, then changing some code to start writing to both columns, then changing all consumers and finally removing the old column. Each as separate, independent, backwards compatible changes.

In short, I doubt there is some magic deployment method that you can use to deploy multiple independent systems with dependencies at the same time ( at least not without accepting down time ).

The solution is to architect the changes to be broken down in small backwards compatible changes until you are done and can finally cleanup/remove the old code.

This BTW, is why systems accumulate technical debt. As time passes and the system grows in complexity, a major upgrade may be too hard to break down and implement like this, so you are forced to make compromises that take time to cleanup.

Anyway, maybe somebody else can describe some black magic but as I said, this is not a deployment issue but an architecture issue.

Hope that helps

Comment: Makes sense, and I definitely agree the main goal when designing changes in microservices the goal is that each service can be updated independently. But even with the best intentions, there are going to be features / changes that end up being coupled. I'd like to have a deployment configuration that supports these type of deployments

Comment: But how do you imagine such a thing other than duplicating the whole thing, which itself has a lot of complication. There is always a way to break the problem into backwards compatible chunks. Trust me on this

Comment: At the end of the day, you need to be able to run the old and new code at the same time, which implies duplicating everything so you can do blue-green on the whole thing, or you incrementally deploy it ( which is what I believe most do )

Comment: I guess I was curious about other approaches. I was wondering if there was some sort of 'transactional deploy' approach. I'm relatively new at working with AWS and continuous deployment in general, so I guess I don't know what I don't know yet.

Comment: Also, I do agree the other approach appears to be to duplicate the entire set of microservices, which seems to defeat the purpose of microservices at some level.